# Passing constructor arguments to the CREATE assembly instruction in solidity

Tags: solidity, assembly, constructor, create

I have a contract which deploys other contracts by bytecode:

```
contract DeployContract {
    function deploy(bytes calldata _bytecode) external returns(address addr) {

        bytes memory bytecode = abi.encode(_bytecode, msg.sender);
        assembly {
            addr := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))
            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to deploy contracts which take an address as argument in their constructor. Appending the address to the bytecode as above does not work. How do I pass the constructor parameter?

Comment: You need to abi-encode them, and then append the result at the end of the bytecode, before passing it to the `create` function.

Answer (score 13):

This worked for CREATE2. Maybe it also works on CREATE?

```
abi.encodePacked(bytecode, abi.encode(arg1, arg2))
```

Example (CREATE2)

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;

contract Wallet {
    address public owner;
    uint public foo;

    constructor(address _owner, uint _foo) public {
        owner = _owner;
        foo = _foo;
    }
}

contract Factory {
    event Deployed(address addr, uint256 salt);

    function getCreationBytecode(address _owner, uint _foo) public pure returns (bytes memory) {
        bytes memory bytecode = type(Wallet).creationCode;

        return abi.encodePacked(bytecode, abi.encode(_owner, _foo));
    }

    // NOTE: call this function with bytecode from getCreationByteCode and a random salt
    function deploy(bytes memory bytecode, uint _salt) public {
        address addr;
        assembly {
            addr := create2(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode), _salt)

            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }

        emit Deployed(addr, _salt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to abi-encode the input arguments, and then append the result at the end of the bytecode before passing it to the `create` function.

Suppose you have input arguments `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`.

I believe that you can more or less achieve that by changing this:

```
bytes memory bytecode = _bytecode;
```

To this:

```
bytes memory bytecode = abi.encode(_bytecode, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

I haven't tested it, so feel free to do it and report back...

Comment: I tested it and it didn't work for me. Maybe there is something wrong with how I am giving the bytecode to the `create` instruction

Comment: I have researched a bit more and changed the code a little bit. I have edited my original question with the new code. It still does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @goodvibration the mistake in this code is that the constructor arguments have to be encoded using `abi.encode`, but then the final result has to be concatenated with the bytecode using `abi.encodePacked`.

Comment: It might be a good idea to use `bytes.concat` instead of `abi.encodePa cked`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to encode arguments with `abi.encode` and bytes with `abi.encodePacked`. Compiles with Solidity 0.4.0.

```
contract DeployContract {
    function deploy(bytes  _bytecode) external returns(address addr) {

        bytes memory bytecode = abi.encodePacked(_bytecode, abi.encode(msg.sender));
        assembly {
            addr := create(0, add(bytecode, 0x20), mload(bytecode))
            if iszero(extcodesize(addr)) {
                revert(0, 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```